# How create SSL Socket with IPv6 IP addresses?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

In the client, I get the address of the server after an UDP multicast (IPv6).
So, I have the server's IPv6 address and I want a create a socket linked to it :

Below you will find extracts from my code that I hope will help you to understand the exception I get.

I get an error when I want to create the SSLSocket :

**client.java**

```
try{
        System.out.println("IP: \n"+this.IP_ADDRESS);
        this.sslSocketFactory = this.sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        this.sslSocket = (SSLSocket) this.sslSocketFactory.createSocket(this.IP_ADDRESS, this.CLIENT_PORT);
    } 

catch (java.rmi.UnknownHostException e){
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + this.IP_ADDRESS);
    } 

catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: " + this.IP_ADDRESS);
    }
```

**Output**

```
IP: 
/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:1
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: /fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:1
```

I'm wondering if there is an exception because of the IP format (that "/" in front of the address) or because its an IPv6 address.

Type of `IP_ADDRESS` is `InetAddress`

**EDIT 1**

Here is how I get the IP Address : 
I send UDP Datagrams to the server and I check its response :

```
                // Check if message is correct
                String message = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
                System.out.println(message);
                if (message.equals("SERVER_POSITIVE_RESPONSE")){
                    this.IP_ADDRESS = receivePacket.getAddress();
                    break;
                }
```

**EDIT 2**
I had `e.printStackTrace` and here is what I get

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Have you used inet6 address like said in the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html

Comment: First I declare **IP_ADDRESS** as an `InetAddress`, then I tried as a `Inet6Address`. But I can't do it because the method `.getAddress()` on a Datagram returns an InetAddress (see my **EDIT**)

Comment: Is your JVM using `preferIPv4Stack` set to `true`? You gotta false that out, because this overrides usage of IPv6 stack

Comment: I just added these 2 first lines (I already had the 2 last ) but nothing change. 

`System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "false");
 System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Address" , "false");
 System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Stack" , "true");
 System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Address" , "true");`

Comment: it's `addresses`, not `address`... I think..??

Comment: You´re right. I change my code in the client and server but the errors are still there.